# Put in a new clutch

Tags: ford, truck

I bought a 93 idi the clutch was bad so I replaced it with a new one and s throw out bearing when I got everything put back together started the truck up and put it into gear and the truck won’t move it boggs down and if I have truck in neutral and let out on the clutch the truck wants to move. I’ve never heard or have had this happen before can anyone tell me what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there is something wrong with the gearbox (transmission) or the selector mechanism.  The gearbox clearly isn’t in neutral when you think neutral is selected, or the vehicle wouldn’t move.

For it to “bogg down” when you select a gear, (which I presume you mean that the vehicle doesn’t move but there is load on the engine which would cause the engine to stall if the clutch was engaged), the gearbox sounds like it is jamming up like there are multiple gears selected.  This would also fit with the fact that the vehicle moves when neutral is selected.

It don’t see how this can be the clutch causing this issue, since you are able to successfully disengage the drive when you press the pedal.

Is the selector stick attached to the gearbox?
Did you remove the selector from the gearbox?